# System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException occuring under ExceptionShielding

Tags: wcf, exception, enterprise-library

We are using the Enterprise Library 4.1 Exception Handling Application Block's ExceptionShielding feature in combination with a custom RoleProvider with our WCF services.

When the RoleProvider determines an user is not in a role and returns false from the IsInRole method, the following exception is occurring:

```
    System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    No signature message parts were specified for messages with the '{XXX}' action.
```

WCF then aborts the `RequestContext` of the service operation, and the client times out.

I have attempted the solution referred to at this link with no success:

http://www.codeplex.com/entlib/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=25236

We also removed the `System.Exception` exception type from the EHAB policy, effectively having EHAB doing nothing for this policy, and this has no effect.

The only thing that prevents this exception is commenting out the `ExceptionShielding` attribute on the service implementation.

Any fix for this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours and hours trying to find out the reason.
I have posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650846/using-ierrorhandler-and-tcp-message-security-causes-a-timeout/4367726#4367726).

Basically you need to define the Fault Action and set it to the same namespace.